# Do jquery still functions same with additional dom element via ajax as already displayed dom element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am submitting a form through ajax and displaying the added field on the same page, along with edit and delete button.. The already added fields are displayed on page load and further addition are displayed via ajax..The delete button (added after ajax from submit ) is not taking any action on click even as on page load delete button.. 
Am i getting some misconception on jquery and getting it wrong and how can i make it working

The already added field from db are

```
....
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
    {
        $("#edit2").click(function(e) { 

           $("#username").val($("#u_name_2").text());
           $("#uemail").val($("#u_email_2").text());  
           $("#editdata").html('Edit and Save')  ;
          $(".hiddclass").val('2');
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="info_2">
                      <div id="formdisplay">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                          <tbody><tr>
                            <td> Username</td>
                            <td id="u_name_2">Sachin</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td> Email :</td>
                            <td id="u_email_2">sachin@india.com</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                      </div>
                      <a class="btn btn-info" id="edit2" type="button" href="#editform">Edit</a>
                       <a class="btn btn-danger delete" id="delete_2" type="button" href="#editform">Delete</a>
                    </div>
....
```

After for submission on ajax, the display values are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
        {
            $("#edit14 ").click(function(e) { 

               $("#username").val($("#u_name_14").text());
               $("#uemail").val($("#u_email_14").text());  
               $("#editdata").html('Edit and Save')  ;
               $(".hiddclass").val('14');
            });
        });
    </script>
<div id="info_14">
      <div id="formdisplay">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td> Username</td>
            <td id="u_name_14"> ghg</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> Email :</td>
            <td id="u_email_14">hj</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-info" id="edit14" type="button" href="#editform">Edit</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger delete" id="delete_14" type="button" href="#editform">Delete</a>

    </div>
```

On click of delete button I am calling the jquery which is working fine with already displayed div from db, but for second case when I am calling the div form ajax the delete button is not functioning as with case 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
    {
$(".delete").click(function(e) { 

            var r=confirm("Sure Want To Change Status?")
            {       
                $id=$(this).parent().attr('id');

                alert($id);
                    $.ajax({
                            type:'GET',
                            url: "include/process.php",
                            data: {id: $id, todel:'Delete' },
                            cache: true,
                            async   : false,
                            error: function(){
                                alert ('error');
                            },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert(data);
                                // on_success_my_action



                            }
                        });
                    return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) { };

Comment: If you have answered you would have got +1  :) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want manage dynamic created content, you have to use .on() :
https://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery only allows to manage content already here when the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$(".delete").live('click',(function(e){
          //write your action})
   )`